# javascript data visualization using bar graphs

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, javascript-objects

I am trying to do data visualization using javascript to construct bar graphs. I am encountering problems when trying to render the graphs. I keep getting the message 'TypeError: rates is not iterable' in the console which refers to the for loop in the render function. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
console.log('running js for currency rates');

doFetch()


function doFetch(){
    fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Got the data!');
        console.log(data);
        let rates = data.rates;
        let base = data.base;
        let date = data.date;
        console.log(rates);

        render(rates)
    });
}


function render(rates){
    const currencyName = Object.keys(rates);
    const values = Object.values(rates);
    let chart = document.querySelector('.BarContainer');
    chart.innerHTML = "";

    for(let rate of rates){
        let bar = document.createElement('div');
        let baseHeight = 100;
        bar.classList.add('Bar');
        bar.style.height = baseHeight + 'px';
        bar.textContent = currencyName;
        chart.appendChild(bar);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for/of` works on [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol), and an Object isn't iterable. You might be looking for `for/in`.

- [for/of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [for/in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 1):

Because `rates` are literal object. And `for of` works for Javascript Array. I think you need to use `for in` instead.

Here is what should be

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="BarContainer"></div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>

console.log('running js for currency rates');

doFetch()


function doFetch(){
    fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Got the data!');
        console.log(data);
        let rates = data.rates;
        let base = data.base;
        let date = data.date;
        console.log(rates);

        render(rates)
    });
}


function render(rates){
    const currencyName = Object.keys(rates);
    const values = Object.values(rates);
    let chart = document.querySelector('.BarContainer');
    chart.innerHTML = "";

    for(let rate in rates){
        let bar = document.createElement('div');
        let baseHeight = 100;
        bar.classList.add('Bar');
        bar.style.height = baseHeight + 'px';
        bar.textContent = currencyName;
        chart.appendChild(bar);
    }

}

</script>
<html>
```